# How do I use useEffect to save a background color state?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, local-storage, redux-toolkit

I am trying to save the background colour of my wishlist toggle button so that when the user travels across pages the colour of button remains "black" to show the user they have already saved the item to their wishlist.

```
const Item = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [background, setBackground] = useState(false);

  function addToCartHandler(product) {
    dispatch(addToCart(product));
  }

  function toggleWishlistHandler(product) {
    dispatch(toggleItem(product));
    setBackground((current) => !current);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <li className={classes.item}>
        <img src={props.img} alt="Item" className={classes.image} />
        <div className={classes.description}>
          <p className={classes.title}>{props.title}</p>
          <p className={classes.price}>£{props.price}.00</p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <div
            className={`${classes.addWishlist} ${classes.icon}`}
            onClick={() => toggleWishlistHandler(props.product)}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: background ? "black" : "orange",
            }}
          >
            <i className="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
          </div>
          <div
            className={`${classes.addCart} ${classes.icon}`}
            onClick={() => addToCartHandler(props.product)}
          >
            <i className="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Comment: You could check if the item exists in the users wishlist instead of saving the color. Unless you need different dynamic colors, something like `user.wishlist.includes(item.id) ? 'black' : 'orange'` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the color in local storage.

```
// Check if it's set to black
  const [background, setBackground] = useState(localStorage.getItem('wishlistBackground') === 'black');


// Save the background color to local storage whenever it changes
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('wishlistBackground', background ? 'black' : 'orange');
  }, [background]);
```